# Simple localized mail server and client

Tags: java, email, apache-camel

I am trying to develop Apache Camel applications that will allow our research project to be able to inject various forms of application-level network traffic into a target application. We want to be able to simulate traffic flows of various types, e.g. file transmissions via FTP, email transmissions, HTTP transmissions via HTTP GET and POST, video streaming and the like. We also need the ability to control the flow (i.e. transmission rate and data size).

The focus of this post deals with email. I know almost nothing about email servers or clients or how they work. My plan is to set up the appropriate Camel routes on the target side to be able to send and receive email traffic, but I have no idea what I need at the other end of the pipeline.

All of the email traffic will be contained within a local network and never needs to go out "on the web". I'd would rather be able to use email servers that are as simple as possible and can be run within our environment.

I have done a little experimentation and have successfully set up a Python-based SMTP server that I was able to send mail *to* from either a Python client app, or a Camel-driven Java app. These apps are very small and simple and work well.

I can't seem to figure out how to be able to *get* mail from the server (see related post [Problem connecting to Python mail server from Java Camel application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505319/problem-connecting-to-python-mail-server-from-java-camel-application)). I've been given the impression that an SMTP server can only be used to transmit messages (send, reply or forward) and that I need some other type of server to be able to retrieve mail *from* a server.

Could someone give me an idea of how I could solve this problem? Are there non-SMTP mail servers that handle requests for mail from a client? If so, what is their availability? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

As per suggestions from @Alexey R, I have taken a look at and attempted to use Greenmail (http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/#). It seems to be well documented, but I'm not having much luck getting it to work. I'm sure it's because I have no idea what I'm doing ;)

One thing that confuses me somewhat, is that most of the examples seem to be in the context of running unit tests. I am not trying to perform unit or integration tests on anything, rather I just need the ability to send and receive email messages.

Here are my experiments so far:

(**Note**: they are separate Spring Boot apps, run with: VM args **-Dgreenmail.verbose -Dgreenmail.auth.disabled**)

MailSender.java:

```
@Service
public class MailSender {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailSender.class);

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
  public void send() throws IOException, MessagingException {
    GreenMail gm = new GreenMail(ServerSetupTest.SMTP_POP3_IMAP);

    // Do I need to do this? What does it do?
    gm.setUser("receiver@mail.com", "receiver", "");
    gm.setUser("sender@mail.com", "sender", "");

    // What, exactly, is being started (and stopped)?
    gm.start();

    GreenMailUtil.sendTextEmail("receiver@mail.com", "sender@mail.com", "Subject", "Test message",
        ServerSetupTest.SMTP);
    logger.info("sent mail");
    // How do I verify it actually HAS been sent? Where did it go? Has it been stored somewhere?

    gm.stop();
  }

}
```

MailReceiver.java:

```
@Service
public class MailReceiver {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailReceiver.class);

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
  public void receive() throws IOException, MessagingException {
    GreenMail gm = new GreenMail(ServerSetupTest.SMTP_POP3_IMAP);

    // Do I need to do this? What does it do?
    gm.setUser("receiver@mail.com", "receiver", "");
    gm.setUser("sender@mail.com", "sender", "");

    // What, exactly, is being started (and stopped)?
    gm.start();

    // What is the difference between the two attempts below?

    // Attempt 1 - use getReceivedMessages - never gets anything

    MimeMessage[] messages = gm.getReceivedMessages();
    logger.info("getReceivedMessages: {} messages", messages.length);

    for (MimeMessage m : messages) {
      logger.info(m.toString());
    }

    // Attempt 2 - create a session, get a bunch of stuff, try to get messages

    Session imapSession = gm.getImap().createSession();
    Store store = imapSession.getStore("imap");
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();
    logger.info("inbox.getMessages: {} messages", msgs.length);

    gm.stop();
  }

}
```

I've tried various tests, some with the standalone Greenmail server running, some without.

For the MailSender, if I run it all by itself (no standalone running), it executes with no exceptions, but I have no idea how to verify if anything actually *was* "sent". If I run it with the standalone running, I get port binding conflicts, which I guess kind of makes sense (but what do I do to correct it?).

For the MailReceiver there are two variations:

1. Attempt 1
2. Attempt 2

Attempt 1 with nothing else running, never receives any mail.
Attempt 1 with the standalone also running, results in port binding conflicts.

Attempt 2 with nothing else running throws an exception that it's not connected.
Attempt 2 with the standalone also running, results in port binding conflicts.

I don't understand the difference or use cases of these two approaches. I basically just copied them from examples and tried to see if they would work. I really have no idea what they're doing (or trying to do).

For the most part, I think I understand why I'm seeing the results I'm getting, but I'm left mystified as to what I need to do to "do it right". I think in a more basic sense, I really just don't know how to properly use the API to achieve my goals.

**UPDATE 2**:

After more research and digging, I'm beginning to understand that SMTP and IMAP (or POP3) mail servers have different and complementary roles. SMTP is mainly for sending mail (relaying or forwarding as well), while IMAP is more for receiving mail. Please correct me if I'm wrong in that description.

It would seem then that if I'm going to try to have an "email system" available that the "target" application will either send mail *to* or receive mail *from*, I need to implement (or make use of an existing implementation) *both* an SMTP and IMAP server. It would also seem that the SMTP server would need to make a mail sent from a sending client available to the IMAP server so that a receiving client can request it. Does that all make sense?

If this is more or less the right view, what recommendations are there for simple SMTP and IMAP servers? Also, do each of these need a complementary client? There is so much of this I don't understand. I am not opposed with using either existing (preferably free and open source) solutions, or if it's easy enough to understand and implement (good documentation!), writing my own.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/

Comment: Quick question: Does Greenmail require that you use it in a unit test context or environment?

Comment: You can use it either as a standalone solution or in context of your app runtime (part of unit tests or an app itself)

Comment: This is the post about how to configure standalone green mail and use it with a regualr mail client (hope this will help to manage to load mail using Camel - after all the concept is the same). https://www.webelement.click/en/greenmail_setup_mock_to_test_emailing_with_greenmail